# How to refresh the php page in webview

Tags: php, android

Please guide me how i can refresh the page in the webview . I am using this

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="3">
```

to refresh my php page but its not working . For the server it is working well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<?
Header('Refresh:3;url=/');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=index.php'>
```

If this doesn't do what you want, please add additional information.

Comment: Check your quotes - `content='0;URL='index.php'`.